# executable generated from python script with pyinstaller is not handling ctrl+z interrupt as expected

Tags: signals, pyinstaller

I am working on a python script(test.py) which needs to handle ctrl+c and ctrl+z. using signal handler(signal.signal) to achieve this.
when the script is executed directly ie., python3 test.py ,ctrl+c and ctrl+z are getting handled.

test.py

```
 import signal
    import time

    def handler_c(signum, frame):
        print("caught ^C")
    def handler_z(signum, frame):
        print("caught ^Z")

    def test():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler_c)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler_z)
        time.sleep(50)
    
    test()
```

```
python3 test.py
^Ccaught ^C

^Zcaught ^Z

^Ccaught ^C
```

when a binary is generated with pyinstaller for the above script and tried to interrupt the binary execution with ctrl+c and ctrl+z,
ctrl+c got handled properly. but ctrl+z is not handled properly. Though the handler got executed, the process is getting suspended.

```
# pyinstaller --onefile test.py

./dist/test (test is the binary generated with pyinstaller)

^Ccaught ^C
^Zcaught ^Z

[1]+  Stopped                 ./dist/test
```

Python 3.6.8, PyInstaller: 4.10

how to handle ctrl+z in the binary generated with pyinstaller?